# Move an app to applications when it's installed itself elsewhere

Tags: applications, install, folders

I installed SmartGit on my iMac, and it put itself in the `Eric's iMac` folder, adjacent to `Macintosh HD`.

[image]

When I open the `SmartGit 18.1.2` folder, it has the following contents:

[image]

It would be nice if I could have SmartGit in the applications folder. What's a good way of doing this without screwing up the operation of the application? I could just dry moving/copying the `.app` file to the applications folder...

If it's easiest just to leave it there, I really don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: drag `SmartGit.app` to your applications folder (or wherever you want to install it) and eject (remove) the img (drag this SmartGit 18.1.2 folder to trash bin)

You didn't install it yet, you only opened a disk image (hint, the format of the file you downloaded is probably `.dmg`) which contains the app itself (the `.app` file). You can now drag this app to your applications folder or wherever you want it. Usually these installers contain these steps, and a shortcut to default applications folder, so you just drag a few steps. But it's the exact same thing.